# Wake on Lan for Linksys WRT54GS

Tags: firewall, router, linksys, wake-on-lan

I have a Linksys router WRT54GS V1 Firmware version 4.71.4. I am having issues getting the router to allow me to use wake on lan over the internet. If I send a magic packet to the local subnet it works fine but if I attempt to do it from the internet I get nothing.

I set the subnet mask of my router to 255.255.255.128. I have enabled port forwarding to UDP port 9 and ip address 192.168.1.127. It sill does not work. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I have not had a chance to try all the suggestions yet. I will hopefully try it this evening.

UPDATE 2: I was finally able to make this work. I was never able to make the WOL work with the linksys firmware so I had to install DD-WRT. Once it was installed I added a Port Forwarding rule to 192.168.1.255 for UDP ports 7&9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the packet to the broadcast address of the network. You can't send it to 192.168.1.127, because the PC is powered off and so this IP is not owned/bounded by him.
Set it to 192.168.1.255

Comment: See resolution in question but your answer was the hint I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your router is supported by [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org). You can install it on that box and then use ssh (on windows putty) to access your router from anywhere in the world. Then you can run the wakeonlan utility on the box itself to wake up the machine in question.

Wake on lan packets only work on a local networks (it is not routable as it is Layer2 traffic).

There is an [article regarding wake on lan](http://oldwiki.openwrt.org/Wake(2d)On(2d)LAN.html) in the OpenWRT wiki.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

If you're trying to send a WoL packet through the internet, it ain't gonna happen. Network admins routinely filter these packets.

If you're trying to send the WoL packet from the router firmware, that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/6790) out.

Otherwise, possible causes:

The network you are starting out from is probably not letting it get out.

The firewall on your wrt54gs is blocking it (try temporarily disabling "Block Anonymous WAN Requests" or other features).

In all cases, look in the logs to see if anything came through.

It is better to (if possible):

- set up a simple web server/CGI script
- set up a simple script that is called from inetd
- send the WOL packet to a different port (port number does not matter) to try to get around intervening firewalls.

You might try leaving the target up so that you could sniff the network.

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-monitor.aspx) is full of goodies that may help in your diagnosis.

Personally, I was in the same position as you with that router. Never was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

THis may be simple and maybe I am not understanding the issue, but can any inbound traffic travel through the router (non web traffic such as RDC)?

What if you put a specific machine in the DMZ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I put the machine in the DMZ and it had no effect. I am using RDC and forwarding it to port 3391 which is working fine as long as the computer is awake.